# Solving a system of 6 ode - varying parameter -CLOSED

Tags: matlab, ode

I am having a system of 6 ode.

What i am trying to manage, is to solve it, for several different values of one of its parameters, parameter 'p', using a for loop at the integration.

I have managed to do it using ode45, however,
using a non-built-in integrator, it seems i am making a mistake and I don't get back the same values, or graphs.

I would appreciate any feedback on my code on what went wrong

Using ODE45

```
p = -100:+1:350;
time = 0:.05:3;
initial = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
x = NaN(length(time),length(initial),length(p));

for i=1:length(p)

    [t,x(:,:,i)] = ode45(@ode,time,initial,[],p(i));

end
figure(1)
plot3(squeeze(x(:,1,:)),squeeze(x(:,2,:)),squeeze(x(:,3,:)))

function dx = ode(~,x,p)
    bla bla
end
```

Using the non-built-in integrator

```
figure
hold all

for p = -100:+1:350
    inicond = [0 0 0 0 0 0];
    dt = 0.01;
    time = 0:dt:10;

    [y] = integrator(@ode,inicond,time,dt,p);
    x1 = y(:,1);
    x2 = y(:,2);
    x3 = y(:,3);
    figure(1)
    plot3(x1,x2,x3)
    axis equal
    legend('-DynamicLegend')
end

function [y] = integrator(ode,inicond,time,dt,p)

    y = NaN(length(time),length(inicond));
    y(1,:) = inicond;

  for j=2:length(time)
      k1 = dt*ode(y(j-1,:),p);
      k2 = dt*ode(y(j-1,:)+k1/2,p);
      k3 = dt*ode(y(j-1,:)+k2/2,p);
      k4 = dt*ode(y(j-1,:)+k3,p);
      y(j,:) = y(j-1,:) + k1/6+k2/3+k3/3+k4/6;
  end   
end


function [dydt] = ode(y,p)
    bla bla
end
```

Using the non-built-in function to solve Van der Pol for multiple 'epsilon'values: This works., while for the previous it doesnt..

```
    figure
    hold all
for epsilon = 0:.2:5
    inicond = [0.2 0.8];        
    dt = 0.1;%timestep for integration
    time = 0:dt:100;

    [x] = integrator(@VanDerPol,inicond,time,dt,epsilon);

    xdot = x(:,2);
    x = x(:,1);
    figure(1)
    plot(x,xdot,'DisplayName',sprintf('epsilon = %1.0f',epsilon))
    figure(2)
    plot3(time, x,xdot)
    axis equal
    legend('-DynamicLegend')
end

function [x] = integrator(VanDerPol,inicond,time,dt,epsilon)

x = NaN(length(time),length(inicond));
x(1,:) = inicond;
%%% ACTUAL CALL OF INTEGRATOR  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%   
    for j=2:length(time)
        k1 = dt*feval(VanDerPol,x(j-1,:),epsilon);
        k2 = dt*feval(VanDerPol,x(j-1,:)+k1/2,epsilon);
        k3 = dt*feval(VanDerPol,x(j-1,:)+k2/2,epsilon);
        k4 = dt*feval(VanDerPol,x(j-1,:)+k3,epsilon);
        x(j,:) = x(j-1,:) + k1/6+k2/3+k3/3+k4/6;
    end   
end


function [dxdt] = VanDerPol(x,epsilon)

dxdt=NaN(1,2);

dxdt(1,1) = x(:,2);
dxdt(1,2) = epsilon*(1 - x(:,1)^2)*x(:,2) - x(:,1);

end
```

I am afraid that with the second way, the values of all the repetitions might not be stored correctly and for this reason the values of the occurring matrices after integration, hardly vary one from another

Comment: In the second, your solution is in `y`, but you plot `(x1,x2,x3)`? Did you try this on a clean work space?

Comment: yes, i just subtracted many lines to save some space. I have edited it now with the missing lines

Comment: I can see no error in the methods resp. code. Could you describe the error further in quality and quantity? Do you observe similar errors if you compare these methods for some one- or two-dimensional ODE system? Is there a difference if you change the step size?

Comment: excellent questions: 
1. i calculated the x1,x2,x3 or y1,y2,y3 in order to compare the rank of these matrices for all p values. With the ODE45 the rank of all three is 60! It is almost full rank. With the questionable integrator, the rank is max 2! Mind that I use the exact same initial conditions and parameters
2. I tried the exact same method for a van der pol with varying 'epsilon'. The results are perfect with the integrator! I will post the van der pol code, too

Comment: rank is a rather blunt instrument in the fuzzy situation of numerical matrices. Your result would still be somewhat consistent over the two methods if you did compare the SVD and the first two singular values were massively larger than the following ones, meaning that the matrices are well approximated by a rank-2 matrix.

Comment: I will definitely test this. If I had to resume the issue in a few phrases:

Solving the 6-equation system for one value of the variable is ok. When I am putting a for-loop, it doesn't work anymore. Although, the exact same method for a 2-equation system, worked fine

Comment: You can get some fantastic insights into the different solver packages from this [Rackauckas blog post](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/comparison-differential-equation-solver-suites-matlab-r-julia-python-c-fortran/). Among others it tells you to not rely too much on matlabs ode45. In general it is advisable to directly control the (absolute and relative) error tolerances.

Comment: This last error is for the first or second method? Are you saying that it is less a problem with the integration method and more an array assignment issue? // If a sample time array is given, you can simplify the return value `[t,x(:,:,i)] = ode45` to `x(:,:,i) = ode45`

Comment: The 'Integrator method' worked well for the 2-equation system. But it does not work well for the 6 equations.
The ODE45 works fine for both.
I cannot understand what I am doing wrong in the case of the 6-equation system to receive so different results. I just follow the lead of the code for the 2-equation code which works fine with the 'Integrator'

Comment: Do you have an estimate for the Lipschitz constant `L` of the system, or at least the order of magnitude of it? In RK4, the product `L*dt` should be somewhere between 0.1 and 0.001. For most toy examples, using 1 as magnitude of `L` is sufficient, in real-life examples this can be radically wrong.

Comment: so you mean that there should be a mistake in the code of the integrator? I didn't think of checking what you are proposing because for the Van der Pol equation the 'Integrator' worked totally fine

Comment: No, these are just the build-in limitations of the RK4 method with fixed steps. For each ODE system there is a range of step sizes where it works well (if it is small, the problem is stiff), but above and below that range the error does not follow the order. Below because of accumulation of floating point errors, with a multi-precision type you can reduce that boundary arbitrarily.